# Why are inotify events different on an NFS mount?

Tags: linux, nfs, inotify

Some time ago I noticed that the events reported by inotify are different when the file is saved to an NFS mount vs. a local file system.

Shouldn't the underlying VFS provide a uniform view of file operations?

The following is the trace of VIM saving a file in Debian 7.1 (Linux 3.2)

On an NFS mount:

```
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 16 (IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
wd=1 mask = 2048 (IN_MOVE_SELF)
wd=1 mask = 4 (IN_ATTRIB)
wd=1 mask = 1024 (IN_DELETE_SELF)
wd=1 mask = 32768 )
```

On a local file system

```
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 16 (IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
wd=1 mask = 2 (IN_MODIFY)
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 8 (IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
wd=1 mask = 4 (IN_ATTRIB)
```

Saving a file with EMACS also reveals different beahvior

On an NFS mount:

```
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 16 (IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
wd=1 mask = 2048 (IN_MOVE_SELF)
```

On a local file system:

```
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 16 (IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
wd=1 mask = 2 (IN_MODIFY)
wd=1 mask = 32 (IN_OPEN)
wd=1 mask = 2 (IN_MODIFY)
wd=1 mask = 8 (IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
```

These tests werer run with [inotify-touch.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/libkqueue/tickets/_discuss/thread/ab1bb661/b50f/attachment/inotify-touch.c)

Comment: vim has a lot of conditional code to figure out how to save the file. Maybe something to do with permissions is changing the code path it takes https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c4ffeddfe5bd1824650e9b911ed9245bf56c69e3/src/bufwrite.c#L1179

Answer (score 4):

#### inotify NFS support?

Looking around the net it would appear that inotify may support NFS but in a very limited fashion.

**exhibit #1**

The reason is explained in this StackOverflow Q&A titled: [inotify with NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs).

*excerpt from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231277/33204)*

> inotify requires support from the kernel to work. When an application
> tracks a directory, it asks the kernel to inform it when those changes
> occur. When the change occurs, in addition to writing those changes to
> disk, the kernel also notifies the watching process.
>
> On a remote NFS machine, the change is not visible to the kernel; it
> happens entirely remotely. NFS predates inotify and there is no
> network level support for it in NFS, or anything equivalent.

**exhibit #2**

Researching a bit more if you look in the [inotify FAQ](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq)

> Q: Can I watch sysfs (procfs, nfs...)?
>
> Simply spoken: yes, but with
> some limitations. These limitations vary between kernel versions and
> tend to get smaller. Please read information about particular
> filesystems.

#### So is it supported?

I think ultimately what you're experiencing is that NFS does not provide an apples to apples equivalent of all the same features as the locally mounted filesystems.

For example *from a [nfs linux thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-nfs/msg34157.html)*:

- CIFS has notification capabilities built in (oplocks)
- NFS provides "leases" for notification

The point here is that alternate filesystem such as CIFS and NFS offer very basic, if any support directly to inotify.

#### NFS v4 state

*excerpt from [IBM article on NFS v4 state](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.idan400/state.htm)*

> NFS version 4 provides a protocol for the client to establish or
> reestablish state, and associates ownership of subsequent server
> stateful operations to previously established states. To resolve the
> absent client problem, the NFS version 4 client must routinely refresh
> the state within the server-specified lease time. Upon lease time-out,
> the server may release resources for the client and make them
> available to other applications.
>
> - A client obtains the server-specified lease time-out attribute by issuing a getattr operation. getattr is not a stateful operation, thus it does not require prior state to be established. A getattr operation may precede a setclientid or setclientid_confirm operation.
> - Refer to the NFS server's leasetime site attribute for setting and tuning lease time periods.
>   *

Comment: The OP appears to be seeing events on NFS, they're just different than the ones seen on local filesystem. The linked question and answer seem to indicate an absence of `inotify` events on NFS.